# AngularJs controller .appendChild() adding up each time view is visited

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a chat feature recently and I notice a curious bug. The following is the code I am using in my controller:

```
    myFirebase.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var msg = snapshot.val();
    var msgUsernameElement = document.createElement("b");
    msgUsernameElement.textContent = msg.user;

    var msgTextElement = document.createElement("p");
    msgTextElement.textContent = msg.message;

    var msgElement = document.createElement("div");
    msgElement.appendChild(msgUsernameElement);
    msgElement.appendChild(msgTextElement);

    document.getElementById("messages").append(msgElement);
  });
```

Suppose we enter the Chat view for the first time, then when I chat, the .appendChild() is working perfectly fine and the typed message shows up in the div 'messages'. Now Suppose we leave the Chat view and re-enter it, and type and send another chat message, then the .appendChild() is executed twice and the same message is appears twice in the div 'messages'. This continues linearly so if we re-enter the controller for the fifth time and send a message, the message is appended to the div 'messages' five times...
What is going on here?

I am using the Ionic Framework and the ready-made app template 'Tabs'. My chat feature is in the chat-details controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because the event handler is being added twice, once when you first visit the chat page, and again when you come back. To confirm that, visit it a third time, and you should see it 3x.

The solution is to put in an `$onDestroy` handler to remove the event handler. If the event handler can't be removed (ie it doesn't have an `off` method), then you should set a variable to tell you that it is initialised, and you check that on initialising the page (to prevent you doing it twice)

Answer (score 0):

So Mikkel gave the right suggestion to initialize a variable and basically use that as a flag to make sure that my event handler is not called multiple times, given multiple entries to the Chat view, but only once. The following is my solution:

```
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("notVisited") == null){ //This initilizes a variable in localstorage
         window.localStorage.setItem("notVisited","true");
    }

    var startListening = function() {
     myFirebase.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
     var msg = snapshot.val();
     var msgUsernameElement = document.createElement("b");
     msgUsernameElement.textContent = msg.user;

     var msgTextElement = document.createElement("p");
     msgTextElement.textContent = msg.message;

     var msgElement = document.createElement("div");
     msgElement.appendChild(msgUsernameElement);
     msgElement.appendChild(msgTextElement);

     document.getElementById("messages").append(msgElement);
    });
    window.localStorage.setItem("notVisited","false");
   }
if (window.localStorage.getItem("notVisited") == "true") {
    startListening();
}
```

Now after implementing this, I ran into a new problem which was that with this new code, each time I re-entered the view, the previous chat messages would not show up. So I added this:

```
        if (window.localStorage.getItem("notVisited") == "false"){
$http({
    url: "https://uniff-f4136.firebaseio.com/" + chatKey + ".json",
    method: "GET"
    }).then(function (response) {
        for (var i in response.data){
            var msgUsernameElement = document.createElement("b");
            msgUsernameElement.textContent = response.data[i].user;

            var msgTextElement = document.createElement("p");
            msgTextElement.textContent = response.data[i].message;

            var msgElement = document.createElement("div");
            msgElement.appendChild(msgUsernameElement);
            msgElement.appendChild(msgTextElement);

            document.getElementById("messages").append(msgElement);
        }
    });
}
```

In the end, this made my chat work though I do not like the repetition of code. I hope others find this insightful. 
Finally, to learn about using firebase to build a real time web chat app, visit this Google CodeLabs link: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-firebase-chat/#4

Comment: You can refactor your code by taking the common code and putting it in a method, just take care to pass things in as parameters and you'll be right. You might also want to look at Meteor (http://meteor.com) as it is a stack that's designed for easy reactive apps (like chat), you simply subscribe to the data, and and changes are sent automatically.